# Aligning Div To The Bottom of a Clickable Flip Card (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a clickable flip image card made using bootstrap and js. I have some information on the back of the card, a title, a main text body and then a few small bits of extra info. I would like these 3 small bits of extra info to be aligned to the bottom of the card. I have wrapped them in a div and tried adding class `"align-self-end"` however this did not work.

Here is the html for my card:

```
        <div class="card mb-4" style="max-width: 300px; min-width: 300px" data-clickable="true">
          <div class="card-inner">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1420x1933" class="card-img" alt="...">
            <div class="card-img-overlay">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text info">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <div class="align-self-end">
                    <p class="card-text smallinfo"><b>1: </b>John</p>
                    <p class="card-text smallinfo"><b>2: </b>Smith</p>
                    <p class="card-text smallinfo"><b>3: </b>2008</p>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the codepen (Click the card to flip it): https://codepen.io/Darlton29/pen/wvKqyBN

I would like the three `<p>` tags inside the `<div>` tag to be at the bottom of the card. Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just modified couple of things in your HTML markup and added some extra CSS code

```
<div class="container">
    <h2 style="margin-bottom: 3rem; margin-top: 1rem;">Align right in Bootstrap 4</h2>
    <div class="card mb-4" style="max-width: 300px; min-width: 300px" data-clickable="true">
        <div class="card-inner">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1420x1933" class="card-img" alt="...">
            <div class="card-img-overlay">
                <div class="cardContent">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card Title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text info">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="alignToEnd">
                    <p class="smallinfo"><b>1: </b>John</p>
                    <p class="smallinfo"><b>2: </b>Smith</p>
                    <p class="smallinfo"><b>3: </b>2008</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .card{
        width: 300px;
        min-height: 408px;
        -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
        perspective: 1000px;
        border: 0px;
        background-color: #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), 0 15px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
        box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), 0 15px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    }
    .card-inner {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
        transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
        -o-transition: transform 0.6s;
        transition: transform 0.6s;
        transition: transform 0.6s, -webkit-transform 0.6s;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }
    .card-title {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.7rem;
    }
    .info{
        font-size: 0.9rem;
    }
    .isbn {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .card.active .card-inner {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    .card img, .card-img-overlay {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        top:0;left:0;right:0;
    }
    .card-img-overlay {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        background:#444c43;
        color:white;
        position:relative;
    }
    .cardContent {
        padding-bottom:60px;
    }
    .alignToEnd {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        display:-webkit-box;
        display:-ms-flexbox;
        display:flex;
        -webkit-box-align:center;
        -ms-flex-align:center;
        align-items:center;
        -webkit-box-pack:center;
        -ms-flex-pack:center;
        justify-content:center;
    }
    .alignToEnd > * {
        width: 100%;
        dispaly:flex;
        -webkit-box-align:center;
        -ms-flex-align:center;
        align-items:center;
        -webkit-box-pack:center;
        -ms-flex-pack:center;
        justify-content:center;
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you- what are the changes to the css actually doing here? I am pretty new to all this, what's with all the -webkit etc?

Comment: First of all I changed the **height** property to be **min-height** as if you have long text this will not stretch and text will overflow.. second I wrapped the content with a div **.cardContent** to make content separate from the sticky text in the bottom, and I gave it a padding bottom of 60px to prevent it overflows the absolute text **Which the accepted answer did not consider that this issue might happen** if you have a long text, and last thing I did prefixed your CSS code to make sure it works properly on all browsers (IE, Safari and Edge...)

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated :)

Comment: I just tested this and for some reason the shape of the card has changed- with this use it is important that the card remains the same size, and that the small bits of info remain vertically stacked, and the size doesn't change- how would I go about fixing this? Thanks

Comment: Can you please update your codepen so i can see what is happening

Comment: Hi, Just make the `.card img` to be `.card img {position:static;}` and set the `.card-img-overlay`  to be `position:absolute;`

this will fix it.

Comment: That fixed the card issue, however the three items at the bottom are still horizontal rather than vertically stacked/ Thanks again :)

Comment: you want them to be on top of each other? if so then just add this style to `.alignToEnd` `-ms-flex-wrap:wrap;flex-wrap:wrap;` and increase the padding of `.cardContent`

Comment: Thank you, that worked for the vertical, I also managed to get them aligned to the left like before- I just changed all mentions of center to left, not sure if that was correct method. Problem is, increasing the padding of card content does not seem to effect anything.

Comment: Try Setting it to flex-end, and the padding will affect if you have along text

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it in the end- there was a small typo on display. What exactly is the .alignToEnd > *  doing?

Comment: This selects all first child elements

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to look into what that means.

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you have wrapped it with the .

You only needed to add this piece of css.

```
.align-self-end {position:absolute;bottom:0}
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't realise it was so simple.